# Що означеє слово "юха"?

Tags: значення-слів

Натрапив на вірш Ю. Андруховича "Мафія" і побачив там такі рядки:

> його червона **юха**, мов сироп і
>   (малиновий), а в центрі капелюха
>   прострелено діру. Літала муха
>   над ним, і плач дівочий із утроб

Пошуки цього слова в СУМі дали [результат](http://sum.in.ua/s/jukha), однак, там пише, що це "юшка". Пошуки в Гуглі привели мене на сторінку [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D1%85%D0%B0) (а також на сторінку російськомовної Вікіпедії, де я виявив, що це ще й назва демона), де пише, що є пустеля із такою назвою.

Проте, здається мені, що це не юшка і точно не пустеля, а кров, однак не можу знайти підтвердження своїм здогадкам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваше припущення, що **юха** - це кров, правильне. У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/umyvatysja) знаходимо:

> **Умитися** кров'ю (мазкою, **юшкою** і т. ін.) — залитися **кров'ю**, будучи побитим, пораненим.

**Юха** — це та сама ж юшка, на підтвердження цього знаходимо статтю **юха** у [Вікіпедіії](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%AE%D1%85%D0%B0)

Comment: Змінив джерело (й цитату трішки) на українське. Якщо ви не проти, залиште так, якщо проти, відмініть редагування, будь ласка.

Comment: @P.Vovk, в принципі, початкова цитата походить с українського першоджерела ([«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), слово «ю́шка» (не «Ю́шка»), розділ «Фразеологія»), просто `http://getword.ru` його спарсили — але можливо, СУМ-11 і справді доречніший.

Comment: @Sasha я ж не проти. Саме тому сказав пані Іванці, що на її розсуд. Бо мої бажання відходу від російського інтернету - одне, а вподобання решти користувачів - інше.